# Excel VBA, cleaning data using if statement and bad email list

Tags: vba, excel, email, data-cleaning

I'm wanting to use an if statement in VBA to help me clean CSV files i have a list of emails that are "bad" and want to add them into the statement so when the program runs it picks up email x, y and z.

I found a youtube video that explained out to remove rows with blank or 0 values, but havent been able to work out if i can expand it.

```
Sub CleanData()

' Disable certain Excel Features, whilst the macro is running
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Decalare Variables
    Dim DeleteRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Set objects
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

        ' Loop through the rows of data, in order to delete rows with a
        ' zero value in column O. Our data commences of row 5
        For DeleteRow = ws.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

            ' Identify values in col O, which are zero & delete entire row
            If ws.Range("O" & DeleteRow).Value = 0 Then
            Rows(DeleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        'Move to next cell in the range, whitch is being looped
        Next DeleteRow

    ' Re-enable the above Excel Features, Whitch were disabled whilst the macro ran
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

in the below section I'd like to add other "bad/unwanted" emails

```
' Identify values in col O, which are zero & delete entire row
If ws.Range("O" & DeleteRow).Value = 0 Then
    Rows(DeleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Any reading or help to point me in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CleanData()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet, delCollection As Range, ckRng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim TestArr(4)  '< Set this to number of strings you have starting at 0

    'Create your array of search values to delete
    TestArr(0) = 0
    TestArr(1) = ""
    TestArr(2) = "a String"
    TestArr(3) = "a String with wildcard*"
    TestArr(4) = "*String with multiple wildcards*"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ckRng = ws.UsedRange.Columns("O")

    For Each cel In ckRng.Cells
        If OrLikeArr(cel.Value, TestArr) Then
            If delCollection Is Nothing Then
                Set delCollection = cel.EntireRow
            Else
                Set delCollection = Application.Union(cel, delCollection)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

    If Not delCollection Is Nothing Then delCollection.EntireRow.Delete

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

### Also, make sure to add the following function to your module:

```
Function OrLikeArr(ByVal compareStr As String, _
    ParamArray compareArr() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long, TestArr
    OrLikeArr = False
    TestArr = compareArr(0)

    For i = LBound(TestArr) To UBound(TestArr)
        Debug.Print "Testing [" & compareStr & "] to [" & TestArr(i) & "] ";
        If compareStr Like TestArr(i) Then
            OrLikeArr = True
            Debug.Print OrLikeArr
            Exit Function
        End If
        Debug.Print OrLikeArr
    Next i

End Function
```

There are *many* ways of accomplishing your goal, but in the one I suggested, you are adding all the rows that meet your criteria - in this case `= 0` - to the range `delCollection`. You can do this by using the `Union` method.

After all the items that meet your criteria are found and added to this range, you will then proceed to delete the range in one hit, as opposed to deleting it line-by-line. This will give you a performance boost by doing it this way.

### EDIT

I just realized that you had set calculation to `xlCalculationAutomatic` at the beginning and end of your code. Updated my code to correct that.

### EDIT #2

I added the function `OrLikeArr` to the answer. You can use this instead of typing out `cel.Value like x or cel.Value like y or cel.Value like z`. This function make the code much cleaner.

But with this being said, I also made a modification to the original code. I added an array, and in that array you will need to input your custom values. One value you stated was `0`, which you can see I added as `TestArr(0) = 0`.

Once you have added all your values to this array, make sure your declaration on `TestArr(i)` is correct. `i` needs to be the total of your test strings - as you can see I stopped with `TestArr(4)`, so thats why it says `Dim TestArr(4)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response,

I tried running that but it made no changes, the "0" in the original code would remove just blank cells in row "o", not sure where i would be add the additional "bad" entities i.e. na@na.com or no@email.com

Comment: Updated code. You can add all the values you want to search for, whether it is `0`, or `na@na.com`, etc. You will need to add these to the array `TestArr()`.